# how can i get all ERC20 addresses in brownie to use in frontend

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, brownie, decentralized-applications

I want to create app like uniswap using brownie and react how can i access all tokens addresses and abi for my project and use it in frontend. How can i implement this in best optimized way ?

Comment: all tokens which ones? all the existing ones?

Comment: Yes active tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to **take information** from a Token like uniswap

uniswap **didn't save** all the existing tokens, that's an impossible thing to do

every time you write the address of a token on uniswap, it makes requests to the smart contract, calling up existing functions thanks to the **ERC-20 standard**

the functions that are called are

```
totalSupply() // to get the total supply

decimals() // to get the number of decimals

name() // to get the name of the token (e.g. Bitcoin)

symbol() // to get the symbol of the token (e.g. BTC)
```

to obtain this data you have to make a call through web3, which will return the data you request

```
// initialize web3
const Web3 = require("web3");

// save only the ABI of the standard, so you can re-use them for all the tokens
// in this ABI you can find only the function totalSupply ()
const ABI = [
     {
         "type": "function",
         "name": "totalSupply",
         "inputs": [],
         "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
         "stateMutability": "view",
         "payable": false,
         "constant": true // for backward-compatibility
     }
];

// run the JS function
async function run() {
     const web3 = new Web3(<YourNodeUrl>);
// create the web3 contract
     const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, <TokenAddress>);
// call the function and get the totalSupply
     const totalSupply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
     console.log(totalSupply);
}
```